# slim 2 Upload image to server with multi part part form from postman

Tags: php, postman, slim

I was creating an API by using Slim framework version 2. I am not able to find any answer about uploading a image to some folder from Postman. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

In Body tab, choose form-data. Hover over the key name and choose File from the dropdown. Then you would be able to upload the file you want from postman.

[image: Pic]